# TFS Widget not showing up as available in dashboard

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have a dashboard for my Default Collection. I added the Analytics widget via the marketplace. The operation seemed successful and I even received an email saying the Widget was installed. When I go to one of my dashboards in the collection to add the widget, it's not in the list of available widgets.

We have TFS2017-SP2 on premise.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Analytics widget is not available for those with TFS on premise.  It's for VSTS only.